# What tool can I use to cut this heavy wire?

Tags: cutting, metal-cutting

I recently had a 40 ft blue spruce tree removed from my front yard.  I dug a hole in that area to put a new tree but noticed there is a solid metal wire inside of this hole.

Maybe this wire was the wrap around the bottom of the old blue spruce?  In either case I tried using cutters, knife, shovel anything and these things do not cut. Is there a strong tool to cut these metal wires out?

Here is a picture of them, they went from gray / silver in color to almost brown probably because they are now exposed:

[image]

Comment: I think I'd figure out what it is before I started hacking away at it. It might be a ground wire. It'll probably cut easily with a bolt cutter or hack saw. What's the question?

Comment: Ground wire to what?  I guess I dont know how to find out what it is.  The question is id like to cut this wire out since I want to plant a new plant there.

Comment: No idea. It doesn't matter. Have you tried tracing it? What buildings or equipment is it oriented toward?

Comment: There is so much of it and so deep I didnt want to continue.  I thought it would be the wire basket around the bottom base of the original tree.

Comment: From the perspective I see, it looks like good wire cutters or fence pliers would cut it. Something like a wire  coat hanger .

Comment: I would never cut a wire I did not know where it went or what it did. It sounds like steel or galvanized wire that could be a tracer for a deeper pipe in my state trees grow like weeds so even a 40' is not very tall or very old. But not knowing what a ground wire is would be a good reason not to cut it until you know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bolt cutter or hack saw will make quick work of it, as would an abrasive blade in a circular saw or angle grinder. It appears to be soft iron judging by the rust.

Comment: It isnt soft at all...it is very hard.  I was scared to use a saw on that darn thing...I tried using pliers and twisting it and it is so strong.

Comment: Do you think it is just the wire basket for the old Tree?  My electricity and cable still work even after some of it has broken off.

Comment: Pliers aren't the right tool. They don't offer enough leverage, which is why bolt cutters exist. I don't know anything about tree baskets.

Comment: And most electrical systems work fine even with their grounding disabled, at least until there's a fault, and then things get dangerous. If it's iron, it's probably not a grounding wire, though.

Comment: Bolt cutter worked - it was just the metal wire basket around the burlap of my old tree.  The cutter was around 15 bucks at Home Depot.  Thanks.